# Dynamic Parameter in Excel PowerQuery with multiple Values

Tags: excel, filter, parameters, powerquery

I built a parameter table for my power query to pre-filter the data that will be loaded into my Excel.
Sort of like [this](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/)

This works quite well for parameters that contain single values. However, this will be not sufficient enough for parameters that contain multiple values.
I would be glad for any input on how I can use multiple values for my parameters to filter my data.
For example: `Para1` should be 10 and 11. Or `Para2` should be the date from 2020/01/01 to 2021/01/01

Here is some of the Source code:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = if Para1 <> null then Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Typ", each ([Value1] = Para1)) else Table.SelectRows(#"Changed typ", each true),

#"Filtered Rows1" = if Para2 <> null then Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows", each ([Value2] = Para2)) else Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Typ", each true),

#"Filtered Rows2" = if Para3 <> null then Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each ([Value3] = Para3)) else Table.SelectRows(#"Filtered Rows1", each true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use two Para's in one filter

```
= Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStep", each [Value4] >= Para4 and [Value4] <= Para5)
```

Or put two "things" in one Para,

```
1/1/2022::1/5/2022
```

and then split them in the code

```
Para4_1= Text.Split(Para4,"::"){0}
Para4_2= Text.Split(Para4,"::"){1}
xx = Table.SelectRows(#"PriorStep", each [Value4] >= Para4_1 and [Value4] <= Para4_2)
```

Note, instead of

```
else Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Typ", each true),
```

you could use

```
else #"Changed Typ",
```

Comment: Thank your! This helped me a lot !